# How to Configure BonitaBPM Platform for BonitaBPMCommunity Tomcat Bundle

Tags: postgresql, bonita

I have tried simple process variable example given at link http://community.bonitasoft.com/project/process-variable-example using BonitaBPMCommunity-7.3.1-Tomcat-7.0.67. Its working well in bonita studio and with default h2 database configuration with tomcat bundle. But when i configure tomcat bundle with PostgreSQL database its not working well with Bonita ui forms but working well with process containing 6.x forms. I have followed database configuration instructions given at official link http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/?page=tomcat-bundle . There is no error in log file at the time of PostgresSQL configuration with bundle. This behavior is because of reason that i am running tomcat bundle "BonitaBPMCommunity-7.3.1-Tomcat-7.0.67" on Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit? I am new to Bonita kindly forgive if i have asked something stupid.

```
Error (when i run process in Mozilla Firefox developer mode):
myProcessVariable is a Process Variable defined in process.

http://localhost:8888/bonita/portal/resource/taskInstance/ProcessVariabl... [HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 0ms]
no element found
In Log file i got error when i submit Instantiation form.
Error evaluating < formOutput > data: $data.processVariableValue is undefinedvendor.min.js:105:441
GET
XHR
```

My Log File:

```
016-12-01 03:11:47.497 -0800 INFO: org.bonitasoft.platform.setup.PlatformSetup System property org.bonitasoft.platform.setup.folder is set to C:\BonitaBPM\BonitaBPMCommunity-7.3.1-Tomcat-7.0.67\setup
2016-12-01 03:11:47.541 -0800 INFO: org.bonitasoft.platform.setup.PlatformSetup Connected to 'h2' database with url: 'jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9091/bonita_journal.db' with user: 'SA'
2016-12-01 03:11:47.545 -0800 INFO: org.bonitasoft.platform.setup.ScriptExecutor configuration for Database vendor: h2
2016-12-01 03:11:47.757 -0800 INFO: org.bonitasoft.platform.setup.PlatformSetup Platform is already created. Nothing to do.
2016-12-01 03:11:47.866 -0800 INFO: org.bonitasoft.engine.EngineInitializer Initializing Bonita Engine...
2016-12-01 03:11:47.866 -0800 INFO: org.bonitasoft.engine.EngineInitializer Initializing Spring context...
2016-12-01 03:11:58.510 -0800 WARNING: org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory HHH000233: Scoping types to session factory org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@ac6f04 after already scoped org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@ac8478
2016-12-01 03:12:02.630 -0800 INFO: org.bonitasoft.engine.EngineInitializer Starting platform...
2016-12-01 03:12:10.080 -0800 INFO: org.bonitasoft.engine.EngineInitializer Platform started successfully
2016-12-01 03:12:10.081 -0800 INFO: org.bonitasoft.engine.EngineInitializer Initialization of Bonita Engine done! ( took 22215ms)
2016-12-01 03:13:41.877 -0800 INFO: org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/bonita] RestletServlet: [Restlet] ServerServlet: component class is null
2016-12-01 03:13:42.396 -0800 INFO: org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/bonita] RestletServlet: [Restlet] Attaching application: org.bonitasoft.web.rest.server.BonitaRestletApplication@1b811b to URI: /bonita/API
2016-12-01 03:13:42.412 -0800 INFO: org.restlet.Component.BonitaRestletApplication Starting org.bonitasoft.web.rest.server.BonitaRestletApplication application
2016-12-01 03:15:43.466 -0800 INFO: org.restlet.Component.BonitaRestletApplication Error while validating expected inputs
Explanations:
Expected input [newVariableValue] is missing
```

Answer (score 0):

In the instantiation form of the "Process variable example" there is no `processVariableValue` variable. The only variable defined in the instantiation form is named `formOutput`. When submit button is clicked the `formOutput` value is sent (see "Data sent on click" property of the button).

So my guess is maybe you edit the form and change the definition of the `formOutput` variable to a JavaScript type and add a reference to a variable named `processVariableValue` that does not exist in the form.

I would recommend to import again the example in the Studio, regenerate the .bar file and try to deploy it again.